# Synchronisation of Redis cache while using Redisson

Tags: redis, redisson

I am using Redis as a caching server. This cache is shared by multiple Java applications. Redisson (Java client for Redis) is used to connect to Redis from the Java application.

There will be scenarios where different applications can try to write/read the data present in Redis cache simultaneously. Should I have a distributed read-write lock for the synchronisation or will Redis handles it by default since it is single threaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hold any lock. All data for single map instance located on the same Redis server.